issues when trying to rename a column and modify the datatype
I am having issues when trying to rename a column and modify the datatype. I can do it separately, but when I try to put them together it can't find either 'Year' or 'ReleaseYear'. It doesn't matter if I put one clause first or second.
This is a practice test question which doesn't show me the CREATE TABLE. They just tell me to ALTER some columns in a table that they created, and the one that I can't get right is the:

DIRECTIONS: Change the Year column's name to ReleaseYear, and change the data type to SMALLINT

DROP and ADD work fine; when I try to rename a column and change the datatype I get the error. Since I changed the name it can no longer can find that column to MODIFY the datatype.
ALTER TABLE Movie
ADD Producer VARCHAR(50),
DROP COLUMN Genre,
MODIFY COLUMN Year SMALLINT,
RENAME COLUMN Year to ReleaseYear;


ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 2: Unknown column 'Year' in 'movie'

Before the call:
Field       Type    

ID          int unsigned    
Title       varchar(30) 
RatingCode  varchar(5)  
Year        int 
Producer    varchar(50)


Use the CHANGE COLUMN clause to change the name and type in one step:
ALTER TABLE Movie
ADD Producer VARCHAR(50),
DROP COLUMN Genre,
CHANGE COLUMN Year ReleaseYear SMALLINT;


Thank you so much! I couldn't find this anywhere!
